# EF Core update entity and child entities in loop - save changes commiting entire list on first pass

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I would like to update one field on a parent table and add the child records in a foreach loop.
The idea is to ensure that each set of records is updated independently beacuse each parent can contain more than 100k child items and if one fails the others should still be attempted.

The parent records already exist in the database and only one field is to be updated and no child records exist yet.

The problem is that the first pass on the for each loop is actually commiting the changes for all the items on the collection instead of a single parent record and its childs. The other passes raises the duplicate primary key exception because it tries again to update and insert all items.
It is as if the foreach is being ignored and everthing is commmited at once - which is too much load and does not ensure each parent, child is an isolated transaction.

What could be causing this behaviour?

```cs
 private async Task<IEnumerable<ParentTable>> SaveChildItems(IEnumerable<ParentTable> itemsToBeSaved)
        {
            var res = new List<ParentTable>();
            foreach(var itemToSave in itemsToBeSaved)
            {
                var strategy = _dbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
                await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async() => 
                {
                    using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var resFile = await _dbContext.ParentTable.Where(x => x.Name == itemsToBeSaved.Name).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                                resFile.FieldToUpdate = enum.UpdateValue;
                                resFile.ChildTable = itemsToBeSaved.ChildTable;
                            
                            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                            transaction.Commit();

                            res.Add(itemToSave);
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception ex)
                        {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                            Log.Fatal(ex, LoggingTemplates.Exception, "Error on parent table file. " + ex.Message, @"\n", ex);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
          
             return res;
        }
```

The code that works for adding each parent record along with its childs in the same app is below. I could change the logic to make work like this but there is processing that depends on the parent record and upserting is not what I am looking for.

```cs
 private async Task<IEnumerable<ParentTable>> SaveRecords(IEnumerable<ParentTable> itemsToBeSaved)
        {
            var res = new List<ParentTable>();
            foreach(var itemToSave in itemsToBeSaved)
            {
                var strategy = _dbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
                await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async() => 
                {
                    using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var resFile = await _dbContext.ParentTable.AddAsync(itemToSave);
                            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                            transaction.Commit();

                            res.Add(itemToSave);
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception ex)
                        {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                            Log.Fatal(ex, LoggingTemplates.Exception, "Error on parent table file. " + ex.Message, @"\n", ex);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
          
             return res;
        }
```

Comment: Not sure, but try to copy variable `itemToSave` to `var itemToSaveLocal = itemToSave` and use new variable inside lambda. It can be bad closure. Also, if there are lot of items, try to recreate DbContext for each iteration to speedup next inserts.

Comment: Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv for the comment. Tried it but did not work out. I edited the original post with code that works for adding parent record with childs without the update.

Comment: Something weird is going on.  You seem to be retrieving records from _dbContext, manipulating the records, but then calling SaveChangesAsync on _appDbContext (a different context).

Comment: Thanks for the catch @NeilW, but it was just a typo when generalizing the code. In the application I have a single context. I edited the original post.

Comment: Ah, Ok.  I guess the same goes for itemsToBeSaved.Name and itemsToBeSaved.ChildTable.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the "parent" tables in itemsToBeSaved being passed into the function were retrieved from the same instance of _dbContext.

In which case they are all being tracked by that context and as soon as you call

```
await _dbContext.SaveChangeAsync()
```

the first time, then EF will automatically update everything that is being tracked by that context.

Those "itemsToBeSaved" being passed in need to be un tracked.

This is what is happening:

```
// Retrieve 2 tables (tracked by the _dbContext))
var parents = _dbContext.ParentTable.Where(x => x.Name == "foo" || x.Name == "bar");

// Assign to two different vars
var tableFoo = parents.where(x => x.Name == "foo");
var tableBar = parents.where(x => x.Name == "bar");

// Put a child table on first one
tableFoo.ChildTable = new ChildTable() { Name = "Fum" };

// Will save ALL parent tables originally retrieved
// and the child table added so far in one go
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

// Too LATE.  tableBar has already been updated.
tableBar.ChildTable = new ChildTable() { Name = "Too" };
```

I think you may be using EF incorrectly.

Try:

```
// Get the parent tables out of the database (without tracking).  They're now not 'attached'.
var parents = _dbContext.ParentTable.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Name == "foo" || x.Name == "bar").ToList();
```

Then dispose of that _dbContext and do all of the work outside of the function where you're making your changes.

Then in your loop create a new instance of the Context for each ParentTable that you retrieve from the database, make the changes, call SaveChangesAsync, then dispose of the context.

Next loop, do the same again.

Keeping a single instance of _dbContext at the class module level might seem logical but it's a bit of a 'gotcha'.  Best to create (and dispose) of contexts as required.

```
foreach ()
{
    // instantiate context with 'using' to enforce disposal
    using (var _dbContext = new DbContext())
    {
        // retrieve records to be updated (NOT with AsNoTracking())
        // make updates to the 'attached' records
        // save changes
        // dispose of context ("using" will automatically call Dispose() at the closing brace
    }
}
```